# Finding canonical names for equivalence classes

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Given $x,y\subset \omega$, define the equivalence relation
$$x=^*y\iff x\Delta y\text{ is finite.}$$
Let $M$ be a ctm of ZFC and $G$ an $M$-generic filter over $P$=Fn$(\omega\times\omega,2)$. Put $g=\bigcup G:\omega\times\omega\to2$ and let
$$a_i=\{n<\omega: g(i,n)=1\}$$
be the $i^\text{th}$ Cohen real.

I know that each $a_i$ has a canonical name, namely (no pun intended)
$$
\dot a_i:=\{(\check n,p):p(i,n)=1\}$$
Can we find any similarly easy names for the equivalence class $[a_i]=\{x\subset\omega: x=^*a_i\}$?

The context for this question is: I'm considering automorphisms of $P$, and I need names for which I can simply describe the action of the automorphism on then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. Let's focus on adding just a single Cohen real $\dot a$.

If $s$ is a finite binary sequence, $\dot a^s$ would be $\{(\check n,p)\mid p\subseteq s\lor s\subseteq p\land p(n)=1\}$.

Now $[\dot a]=\{\dot a^s\mid s\in 2^{<\omega}\}^\bullet$, where $\{\dot x_i\mid i\in I\}^\bullet$ is the name given by $\{(\dot x_i,1)\mid i\in I\}$.

Comment: Admittedly, of all the things I've done, $\bullet$-names is the thing I'm finding most useful.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! :)

Comment: What result are you trying to prove without choice?

Comment: I want to show that the family of pairs $\mathcal{F}=\{ \{[a_{2i}],[a_{2i+1}]\}:i<\omega\}$ does not have a choice function in the model $HOD(\text{trcl}(\mathcal{F}))^{M[G]}$. I couldn't find any references in the literature (the closest was the entry in Jech's *The Axiom of Choice* about Cohen's second model.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is *really* the family you're trying to get there. As a pro-tip, I think that working with the actual automorphism group and a normal filter of subgroups is far better in clarifying these arguments. The HOD based approach is good, it is equivalent even, but it is obfuscating the true reason for these sort of small failures, which is generally given from the right choice of automorphism group and filter of subgroups.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely keep it in mind. In this case the problem I was trying to do asked explicitly about the HOD model.

Comment: By whom? Go back and tell them that's just cruelty. :P